# Scala quasiquote generating parameter default value with backticks

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I need to generate:

```
case class Foo(param: Bar = BarEnum.SomeCaseObject)
```

But this code:

```
val term = TermName("BarEnum.SomeCaseObject") 
showCode(q"""case class Foo(val param : Bar = ${term})""")
```

outputs the parameter default surrounded by backticks, which doesn't compile:

```
case class Foo(param: Bar = `BarEnum.SomeCaseObject`)
```

How can I get the default parameter value output without the backticks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create value with *name* "BarEnum.SomeCaseObject", that's illegal identifier, thus in backticks.

You can use `Select(Ident(TermName("BarEnum")), TermName("SomeCaseObject"))` or (better) `q"BarEnum.SomeCaseObject"` (assuming that `SomeCaseObject` is a term).